# Remove smallest value from array after append to New array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am running a selection sort function in Python that works with numpy arrays instead of lists (so I can't use .pop for this, I don't think).

The function is:

```
def selectionSort(arr):
    newArr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        smallest = findSmallest(arr) 
        newArr.append((smallest)) 
        arr = arr[(arr > smallest)]
    return newArr
```

I want that "arr = arr[(arr > smallest)] which obviously doesn't work, to remove the smallest value (or, the value appended to newArr i.e the same value) from the passed array in the same way that .pop would do with a list.

I've tried things along these lines:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
index = [2, 3, 6]

new_a = np.delete(a, index)
```

But couldn't get it to work. At the end of the day, I need to get something in the format of:

```
arr = randint(0,10,20)
```

to return an array sorted in ascending order. All I can manage is returning the smallest values repeated.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
arr = arr[np.where(arr > smallest)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
arr = arr[ arr != np.min(a)]
```

This way you'll take from `arr` all the elements except the smallest one and reassign them to `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is almost correct. Indeed, it works if there are no duplicate values in `arr`:

```
import numpy as np

def selectionSort(arr):
    newArr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        smallest = findSmallest(arr) 
        newArr.append((smallest)) 
        arr = arr[(arr > smallest)]
    return newArr

findSmallest = np.min

# no duplicate values
auniq = np.random.choice(np.arange(20), (10,), replace=False)

print(auniq)
print(selectionSort(auniq))
```

Sample run:

```
[ 0  1  7  4 10 14 13 16  9 12]
[0, 1, 4, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16]
```

If there are duplicates it will crash because upon removing a minimum with duplicates the duplicates will be removed as well and that throws off the logic of the loop.

```
# duplicate values
adupl = np.random.randint(0, 9, (10,))

print(adupl)
# next line would crash
#print(selectionSort(adupl))
```

One fix is to only remove one copy of duplicates. This can for example be done using `argmin` which returns the index of the/one minimum, not its value.

```
def selectionSort2(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr)
    sorted = np.empty_like(arr)
    for i in range(len(sorted)):
        j = arr.argmin()
        sorted[i] = arr[j]
        arr = np.delete(arr, j)
    return sorted

print(selectionSort2(adupl))
```

This works but is terribly inefficient because `np.delete` is more or less O(n). It is cheaper to swap the minimum element with a boundary element and then cut that off:

```
def selectionSort3(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr)
    sorted = np.empty_like(arr)
    for i in range(len(sorted)):
        j = arr[i:].argmin()
        sorted[i] = arr[i + j]
        arr[i], arr[i + j] = arr[i + j], arr[i]
    return sorted

print(selectionSort3(adupl))
```

Looking at `selectionSort3` we can observe that the separate output `sorted` is not actually needed, because `arr` has been sorted inplace already:

```
def selectionSort4(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        j = arr[i:].argmin()
        arr[i], arr[i + j] = arr[i + j], arr[i]
    return arr

print(selectionSort4(adupl))
```

Sample output (`adupl` and output of `selectionSort2-4`):

```
[0 4 3 8 8 4 5 0 4 2]
[0 0 2 3 4 4 4 5 8 8]
[0 0 2 3 4 4 4 5 8 8]
[0 0 2 3 4 4 4 5 8 8]
```